# AJAX read JSON data from twitter search not work

Tags: jquery, json, search, twitter

I use jquery to retrieve search result from twitter but it does not work, can you address mistake in my code?
Here is form search:

```
<label>Enter keyword: </label><input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" size="50" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="button" name="btnsearch" id="btnsearch" value=" Search " />
```

and here is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
            $("#keyword").focus();
            $("#btnsearch").click(function(){
                var keyword = $("#keyword").val();                          
                if(keyword == null || keyword == "") return;
                $("#results").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");                 
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+keyword+'&rpp=50',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(json){
                        $("#results").remove();
                        alert("Successfull");
                    },  
                    error:function(){
                        alert("cant search");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    );
```

I just test if it work or not, and when I press Search button, it alerts "Cant search"!

Any help?

Comment: If you add a parameter to the error handler, it gives you the error.  Please read that error and post its contents.

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp';` is missing. This has tobe added when doing cross domain calls... refer my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not using **dataType: 'jsonp';** which is a code to be added when you are accessing cross domain data

below is the working code **(i have tried it)**

```
$(document).ready(         
function(){             
$("#keyword").focus();            
$("#btnsearch").click(function(){                 
var keyword = $("#keyword").val();                                           
if(keyword == null || keyword == "") return;                 
$("#results").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");                                  
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url:'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
    data: 'q='+keyword+'&rpp=50',
    success:function(json){                         
    $("#results").remove();
    alert("Successfull");                     
    },
error:function(){                         
alert("cant search");                     
}                 
});             
});         
}     
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! So can we do the same task by using raw javascript? And how to do this mate?

Comment: Ah, I mean instead of using jquery, I just use javascript. How to do this :(

Comment: I suggest you to use Jquery as its more efficient.. if you want to do the same with normal js, then you can create xmlhttp object. Refer http://w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: Thanks, and now I have problem with writing data to text file.! People say that js can not write to file, so I use jsp to do this task, but its hard to assign js variable to jsp code! (PS: i am not allow to use PHP :( )

Answer (score 1):

Demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/cAVsS/1/

Callback should be JSONP:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to access Twitter API from your own webpage. Unfortunately, this kind of access is not allowed by browser for security reason.

You cannot access an API on another server with Ajax/JSON.

For example, assume your web page is hosting on www.myserver.com.  You can access APIs ONLY if they come from www.myserver.com. You cannot access APIs that come from twitter.

This is called "same origin policy".

The solution is creating a proxy on your server with a server-side language such as PHP/Python/Perl. Just google "ajax proxy" for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery code. It does work for me in production

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + keyword + '_de&callback=?', function(json) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

You have to specify the *&callback=?* parameter in order to let jQuery consume the JSON.
Maybe just adding the *&callback=?* will help in your example, but above is how I did it.